# ggplot with multiple lines that works in regular R but not Shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I have a dataframe whose rows are different decisions (order quantities in an inventory setting) and whose columns are the average performance (over several simulations), lower 95% confidence interval, and upper 95% CI.  I want to plot the average curve in red and the lower/upper curves both in blue.  If I run the following in a regular R script, I get the plotting outcome I desire:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = order_quantity_vector)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = expected_profit_vector, color = "red")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = lower_ci_vector, color = "blue")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = upper_ci_vector, color = "blue")) +
  labs(x = "Order quantity", y = "Average profit")
```

However, when I try to embed the above in a renderPlot call in Shiny, I get the following error:

```
Warning: Error in : geom_line requires the following missing aesthetics: x and y
```

I'm not sure why this happens in Shiny but things work fine in the regular .R script.

If instead of trying to plot the 3 lines together in Shiny I just try to plot the average profit curve using the code snippet below, then that works fine. It's in trying to add the lower and upper 95% curves that I run into the error message above.

```
ggplot(reactive_vals$df, aes(x = order_quantity_vector, y = expected_profit_vector)) + geom_line(color = "red") + geom_point() + labs(x = "Order quantity", y = "Average profit")
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?  thanks!

Comment: do you use `ggplot(reactive_vals$df,...)` in shiny or `ggplot(df,...)`

Comment: @Waldi may be on to something, but it's difficult to help you when you give us the code that works and don't give us the code that doesn't!  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimum reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.